# Find $\sigma-\text{algebra}$ on $X$, generated by $\mathscr{M}$ where $\mathscr{M}$ is all subsets have two elements of $X$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find $\sigma-\text{algebra}$ on $X$,  generated by $\mathscr{M}$ where $\mathscr{M}$ is all subsets have two elements of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Try to establish these facts in order:

- The singleton sets are in $\sigma$
- The countable sets are in $\sigma$
- The co-countable sets are in $\sigma$.

From here show that the union of the countable and co-countable sets are a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: (As long as $X$ has more than two elements.)